# C# DataTable Min Value excluding NaN

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.1

I am having a problem with datatable in C#. I want to find the min value for a column in a datatable that has NaN value. For example:

```
c1  c2  c3
1   2   3
4   NaN NaN
NaN 7   9
```

Say if I want to find the min value in c1, I would do:

```
int minValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("min([c1])", string.Empty));
```

or:

```
int minValue = dt.AsEnumerable().Min(r => r.Field<int>("c1"));
```

I am expecting both of them to return an integer value (in this case: 1) However both of them instead returns

```
NaN
```

I am using .NET 4.6.1. Is there a way to tell the datatable to exclude NaN value when computing min value? (Surprisingly no one seems to be having similar question when I am searching this up.)

Comment: Try to filter NaN values with the second parameter of Compute

Comment: so it would be `int minValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("min([c1])", int.NaN));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq's [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) and [Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-6.0) functions:

```
double FindColumnMinValue(IEnumerable<double> columnValues) => columnValues.Where(c => !double.IsNaN(c)).Min();
```